# How do I change my locale to UTF-8 in CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos5, localization, charset, language

Here's the output of `locale`:

```
LANG=zh_CN.GBK
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_NAME="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.GBK"
LC_ALL=
```

How can I change all of them to `UTF8`?
How can I make the locale setting persistent in CentOS 5.5?

Answer (score 16):

In CentOS try with system-config-language command. That's the CentOS way :)
Also you can try with:

```
localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: what's `localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8` for?

Comment: It's used to define your locale to en_US and en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean in the current session or permanently?

If you just need it in the current shell you can export the `LC_ALL` variable. For example:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you mean to do it permanently or system-wide it varies from distribution from distribution. What's yours?

Comment: mine is `centos 5.5`.

Comment: just for session, If you close the item, Next login in  LA_ALL='''

Answer (score 5):

Red-Hat like distros (Centos, SL) come with file

> > /etc/sysconfig/i18n

which contains by default (well, in my case)

> > LANG="en_GB"
> >
> > SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"

And above file is being sourced by /etc/profile.d/lang.sh

I my case I wanted to change en_GB.UTF-8 to en_GB.iso88591
so I found that “proper” way of doing it was to append /etc/sysconfig/i18n with

> > CHARSET="iso8895-1"

Once that done locale for each account on the system should be saying:

> > me@wark:~ $ locale
> >
> > LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
> >
> > LC_CTYPE="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_TIME="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_COLLATE="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_MONETARY="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_PAPER="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_NAME="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.iso88591"
> >
> > LC_ALL=en_GB.iso88591

Answer (score 2):

As I suppose, after your encoding, your are chinese from mainland, you need first the chinese locale :

```
localedef -i zh_CN -c -f UTF-8 zh_CN.UTF-8
```

Then you can export you locale as :

```
export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

if you want to configure this system-wide :

change /etc/locale.conf to:

```
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

The second line is for rules about comparing string.

Or for an user, you can just add it in you ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7, I was able to change the default system language by editing

```
/etc/profile
```

This is where the following variables are set

```
export LANG="en_GB.utf8"
export LANGUAGE="en_GB.utf8"
export LC_ALL="en_GB.utf8"
```